# Read properties file using javascript

Tags: javascript, properties

- I have a db.properties file in my local machine with this value.
- aaa = host,port,username,password
- I have a jsp page with button. On click of a button i need to read properties file value(aaa = host,port,username,password) using javascript

Answer (score -1):

Include the MessageResource.js from [here](https://github.com/suhaibkhan/messageResource.js) this will solve the problem if you are using a simple javascript.

If you are using any script framework it will contain inbuilt functionality to read .properties files. For Example, SAPUI5 contains oBundle functionality to do this.